# how to disable hooks in lifecycles during strapi.db.query oentityService?

Tags: hook, strapi

I'm using Strapi.js version 4.x.
Strapi allows you to have hooks in the collection type lifecycles.js file.

In this file I inserted hooks like `beforeUpdate()` `afterUpdate()` etc.

I need to run an `update()` query on a "model" of the same content-types and i want to avoid entering the lifecycle hook again, otherwise it would loop.
There's a way?
Thanks for the support!
#LongLifeStrapi

```js
module.exports = {

    beforeUpdate: async(event) => {
        // ...
    },

    afterUpdate: async(event) => {

        let id = event.params.where.id

        // My code ...

        // Update of a field of the same collection type
        strapi.db.query('api::my-model.my-model').update({
            where: id, 
            data: {
                myFiled: true
            }
        })
    }
}
```